# Is this a legit way to visualize complex functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, 3d, visualization

I am doing laplace transform in a class and I hate how there seems to be no graphical support when things are transformed to laplace domain i.e. nobody cares what they look like in laplace domain

But I think I have found a short cut, prove me wrong!

Take the laplace transform of y(t) = 1 yields Y(s) = 1/s

Cheat and plot it as a function of real number

[image]

Now I rotate this graph around the z-axis and get a volcano looking thing

Voilà, wolfram alpha seems to approve

[image]

Can anyone opine on whatever little mathematic may be in this approach? Is this method extendable to other functions of complex variable?

This seems to have little mathematical basis but I wonder if I can fight with other laplace transforms (usually rational functions of the form p(s)/q(s)) using similar method and attempt to "visualize" what they might look like in complex domain

Comment: The graph that results when you rotate that around the $z$-axis is not going to be a surface. It will look like two funnels reflected in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: After rotating the right half, you get something like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%28x^2%2By^2%29) rather than what you got.

Comment: your best bet is to plot the magnitude and complex-argument (phase) as separate 3d graphs, just as Wolfram graphs the real and imaginary parts as separate graphs.

Comment: @user1537366: And actually, that's what you get when you rotate around the $x$- or $y$-axes. Rotating around the $z$-axis, like the OP says, just rotates the plot in-plane...